# How do you filter Tabulator data on a class

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm wondering if it's possible to set a filter to filter rows against a class rather than actual table data (so for instance only show rows where a particular class is present)? If so would this have to be a custom filter or can I use the standard filter operators?

FYI I'm using Tabulator v3.5. Any examples would be much appreciated :-)

---

Thanks for the reply Oli.

I've implemented mutators to define a few new properties as per your suggestion but I've got another problem of how to remove a filter for a particular property without using clearFilter which as I understand it clears ALL active filters? I've tried removeFilter but this doesn't seem to work.

For example (when checkbox is ticked):

```
 if (chk) {
  $("#allocations-table").tabulator("setFilter", "Allocated", "=", "is-allocated");
 } else {
  $("#allocations-table").tabulator("removeFilter", "Allocated", "=", "is-allocated");
 }
```

Comment: Ok I've switched to using a combination of addFilter and removeFilter and that seems to work :-)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to filter a row based on class would be a bit of an anti-pattern when it comes to using Tabulator because you would have to use a formatter to apply the class in the first place, at which point you might as well set a property on the row and then filter things the normal way.

The correct approach would be to create a hidden column that uses a [mutator](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/mutators#mutators) to define a new property on the row, lets call it ***class***, then you use a row formatter to apply this to the row, and then you can filter it as normal.

So lets start by creating our mutator, im going to add some arbitrary logic in this to set a class based on the value of another column (lets say age):

```js
var classMutator = function(value, data){
    if(data.age >= 18){
        return "is-adult";
    }else{
        return "is-child";
    }
}
```

Then we want to add that to a column definition, for a hidden column that uses this mutator:

```js
{field:"class", mutator:classMutator, visible:false},
```

Then we will need a row formatter to apply that class to the row:

```js
rowFormatter:function (row){
    row.getElement().classList.add(row.getData().class);
}
```

So all together we have a table constructor that looks like this:

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    columns:[
        {field:"class", mutator:classMutator, visible:false},
        //... other table columns go here
    ],
    rowFormatter:function (row){
        row.getElement().classList.add(row.getData().class);
    }
}
```

Then to filter you can simply using the ***setFilter*** function:

```js
table.setFilter("class", "=", "is-child");
```

As a side note, i would strongly recommend upgrading to the latest version of Tabulator, v3.5 is almost 2 years old at this point, and there have been significant improvements since then. If you are worried about jQuery compatibility, all of the latest versions come with a [jQuery Wrapper]([http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/jquery]](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/jquery%5D) to make migration easier